# Cypress API login does not redirect to homepage

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, refresh-token

I wan't to bypass the UI login to save time in my tests. I have decided to write a before each hook that does the login between it blocks in my tests. The login endpoint returns the following payload structure.

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
          ... 
        },
        "jwt": "...",
        "exp": ,
        "iat": ,
        "refreshToken": "",
        "refreshTokenExp": 
    }
}
```

The hook that should do the log in:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.request(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://some-page/api/v1/auth/login',
                body: {
                    email: 'some-email@mail.com',
                    password: 'password'
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                const jwt = response.body.data.jwt;
                const refreshToken = response.body.data.refreshToken;
                const exp = response.body.data.ext;
                cy.wrap(jwt).as('authToken');
                Cypress.env('AUTH_TOKEN', jwt);
                window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt)
                window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken)
                window.localStorage.setItem('exp', exp)
                cy.visit('/home')
            });
    })
```

the test

```
it('Visit /users page with valid authentication', () => {
        cy.get('@authToken').then((authToken) => {
            cy.visit('/users/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                }
            });
            cy.url().should('contain', '/users')
        });
    })
```

The POST request is executed successfully, and all of the values that are returned by the endpoint get stored in the browser, but the it test always fails as the redirect never happens.

I have tried various versions of the above code, where i store more of the payload that is returned from the login call. Setting more data to the localStorage. Visiting the same pages in the hook and it blocks.

Comment: Did you setup `baseUrl`? - *If the baseUrl has not been set, you will need to specify a fully qualified URL or Cypress will attempt to act as your web server. See the prefixes notes for more details.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving the visit outside the request callback. Cypress sometimes does not like to add commands to the queue from inside a callback

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://some-page/api/v1/auth/login',
    body: {
      email: 'some-email@mail.com',
      password: 'password'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    ...
  })
  cy.visit('/home')
})
```